# Depending on text value, can I stop specific sounds universally?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a button where it changes the value of a text field to 0 or 100 (vice versa). The text field calls the function CheckSound

```
function CheckSound():void
 {
 if(options_mc.onoff_txt.text == "100")
 {
 tchannel = theme.play(0,9999);
 }
 else if(options_mc.onoff_txt.text == "0")
 {
tchannel.stop();
 }
 }
```

The sound stops and plays. When I go to another scene in the game, tchannel stops playing and rchannel starts playing. This is what I want. My question is how can I stop tchannel and rchannel if the value is 0. And if the value is 100, how can I make tchannel and rchannel playable at their right frames?

Answer (score 0):

You can depend on the current scene name to decide which sound to play.

```
import flash.display.Scene;

// ...

function CheckSound():void
{
    if (options_mc.onoff_txt.text == "100")
    {
        playCurSceneSound();
    }
    else if (options_mc.onoff_txt.text == "0")
    {
        stopMySounds();
    }
}

function stopMySounds():void
{
    tchannel.stop();
    rchannel.stop();
}

function playCurSceneSound():void
{
    var curScene:Scene = this.currentScene;
    trace("We are in scene: "+curScene.name);

    // use the Scene name to choose the suitable sound for this scene:
    switch (curScene.name)
    {
        case "Scene 1" :
            tchannel = theme.play(0,9999);
            break;

        case "Scene 2" :
            rchannel = rheme.play(0,9999);
            break;

        default :
            trace("No sound for '"+ curScene.name + "' scene! ");
            break;
    }
}
```